# How to change the case of my github's username without changing any letter?

Tags: github

I want my username to be displayed as `exampleusername` instead of `ExampleUsername`. How can I achieve this ?

Note: When I try with *Change username* I'm said that `exampleusername` is already used (*of course, by me*).

Can I achieve this by moving from "ExampleUsername" to "ExampleUsername298478675675" and then back to "exampleusername" (will it be available ?) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming problem. It would be better addressed as a feature request to GitHub support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usernames are **not case sensitive**.

For example, my username is `dinko-pehar` . https://github.com/DINKO-pehar also redirects to https://github.com/dinko-pehar .

For proof, if you try to register as new user, for example `DINKO-Pehar`, you will get that *Username is not available.*

[image: Username]

---

I can change my name to `dinko-pehar123123`. And username `dinko-pehar` will be available to everyone. **BUT**, I'm not completely sure when changing back to `dinko-pehar`, what consequences will be. Read this [article](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/changing-your-github-username) on Github.

Answer (score 3):

I tried just now, and it worked as expected. Renamed my capital case username to lowercase with no problems. And no side effects, because they already was resolving case insensitive way. The window said lowercase was available, i confirmed and that's it.

But now my nickname is shown and referenced in lowercase for Github itself and everywhere.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).